# Mail : com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 530 5.7.1 Authentication required

Tags: email, jakarta-mail

I am trying to send an Email from my Java Application to any particular email address. I am using JavaMail API but Unfortunately i am getting SMTPSendFailedException error. Can any body tell me where i am doing a mistake. Here is my code

```
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put("mail.smtp.host", "plus.smtp.mail.yahoo.com");
    properties.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
    properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    properties.put("mail.smtp.user", emailId);
    properties.put("mail.smtp.password", password);

    Session emailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties,
            new Authenticator() {
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication(emailId,password);
                }
            });
    emailSession.setDebug(true);

    try {
        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(emailSession);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
        message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,new InternetAddress(to));
        message.setSubject("Ping");
        message.setText("Hello, this is example of sending email  ");

        // Send message
        Transport.send(message);
        System.out.println("message sent successfully....");

    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
```

**when I ran this code I got :**

```
DEBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.4.7
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle]
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth false
DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "plus.smtp.mail.yahoo.com", port 587, isSSL false
220 *.smtp.mail.yahoo.com ESMTP ready
DEBUG SMTP: connected to host "plus.smtp.mail.yahoo.com", port: 587

EHLO Libsys-PC
250-*.smtp.mail.yahoo.com
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE 41697280
250-8 BITMIME
250 XXXXXXXX
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "PIPELINING", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SIZE", arg "41697280"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "8", arg "BITMIME"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "XXXXXXXX", arg ""
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle]
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth false
DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "plus.smtp.mail.yahoo.com", port 587, isSSL false
220 *.smtp.mail.yahoo.com ESMTP ready
DEBUG SMTP: connected to host "plus.smtp.mail.yahoo.com", port: 587

EHLO Libsys-PC
250-*.smtp.mail.yahoo.com
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE 41697280
250-8 BITMIME
250 XXXXXXXX
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "PIPELINING", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SIZE", arg "41697280"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "8", arg "BITMIME"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "XXXXXXXX", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: use8bit false
MAIL FROM:from
530 5.7.1 Authentication required
DEBUG SMTP: got response code 530, with response: 530 5.7.1 Authentication required

RSET
250 2.0.0 OK
DEBUG SMTP: MessagingException while sending, THROW: 
com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 530 5.7.1 Authentication required

    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.issueSendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:2108)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.mailFrom(SMTPTransport.java:1609)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:1117)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:195)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
    at Mail.main(Mail.java:119)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
QUIT
221 2.0.0 Bye
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 530 5.7.1 Authentication required

    at Mail.main(Mail.java:123)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
Caused by: com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 530 5.7.1 Authentication required

    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.issueSendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:2108)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.mailFrom(SMTPTransport.java:1609)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:1117)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:195)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
    at Mail.main(Mail.java:119)
    ... 5 more

    Process finished with exit code 1
```

:

**After reflecting my code is :**

```
     Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put("mail.smtp.host","smtp.gmail.com");
    properties.put("mail.smtp.port", 587);
    properties.put("mail.smtp.auth",true);
    properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    Session emailSession = Session.getInstance(properties);
    emailSession.setDebug(true);

    //create the POP3 store object and connect with the pop server
    try {

        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(emailSession);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
        message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,new InternetAddress(to));
        message.setSubject("Ping");
        message.setText("Hello, this is example of sending email  ");
        Transport.send(message,id,password);

        System.out.println("message sent successfully....");

    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
```

But debug output is same as previous

```
    DEBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.5.5
 DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle]
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "smtp.gmail.com", port 587, isSSL false
220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP i62sm9706430pfg.62 - gsmtp
DEBUG SMTP: connected to host "smtp.gmail.com", port: 587

EHLO Libsys-PC
250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [163.47.140.139]
250-SIZE 35882577
250-8BITMIME
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-PIPELINING
250 SMTPUTF8
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SIZE", arg "35882577"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "8BITMIME", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "PIPELINING", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SMTPUTF8", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: use8bit false
MAIL FROM:<rohitsingla6@gmail.com>
530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. i62sm9706430pfg.62 - gsmtp
DEBUG SMTP: got response code 530, with response: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. i62sm9706430pfg.62 - gsmtp

RSET
250 2.1.5 Flushed i62sm9706430pfg.62 - gsmtp
DEBUG SMTP: MessagingException while sending, THROW: 
com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. i62sm9706430pfg.62 - gsmtp

    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.issueSendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:2249)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.mailFrom(SMTPTransport.java:1740)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:1239)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:255)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:174)
    at GMail.main(GMail.java:32)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
QUIT
221 2.0.0 closing connection i62sm9706430pfg.62 - gsmtp
com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. i62sm9706430pfg.62 - gsmtp

    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.issueSendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:2249)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.mailFrom(SMTPTransport.java:1740)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:1239)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:255)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:174)
    at GMail.main(GMail.java:32)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. i62sm9706430pfg.62 - gsmtp

    at GMail.main(GMail.java:38)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
Caused by: com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. i62sm9706430pfg.62 - gsmtp

    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.issueSendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:2249)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.mailFrom(SMTPTransport.java:1740)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:1239)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:255)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:174)
    at GMail.main(GMail.java:32)
    ... 5 more
```

Answer (score 1):

You should [upgrade to JavaMail 1.5.5](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home) and fix these [common mistakes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes); in particular, you should get rid of the Authenticator and use the [Transport.send method that accepts a user name and password](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/Transport.html#send-javax.mail.Message-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-).  If you can't upgrade, set the proproty `mail.smtp.auth` to `"true"`.  And there is no `mail.smtp.password` property so don't bother setting it.

Comment: Hi, i have changed the code as you said but still it gives the same error. Is there any possibility that firewall is blocking it. Because when i run this from another system on another network it successfully runs.

Comment: What does the JavaMail debug output show after you made the change?  Edit your question with the updated code and output.

Comment: It worked using 465 port. and by adding one more property "mail.smtp.ssl.enable" true. But i don't understand why it is not working with 587 port

Comment: You said you're getting the same error but you're not.  When using port 587 it wants you to use the STARTTLS command before authenticating.  To do that you need to set `mail.smtp.starttls.enable` to `true`.

Answer (score -1):

- **In JAVA Mail API you have to set username and from address same as per documentation of java mail API.so,**
- **This both sentences should look like this in your code , whenever you
  are using JAVA Mail API**

  properties.put("mail.smtp.user", emailId);

  message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(emailId));